# Loading information from a session user

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a page which will allow a user that is currently logged in view their personal information. 
Can I use `$result = mysql_query("SELECT $_SESSION FROM users",$db);` to load the information or is there a better way to load it.

My code works now. This is the code just in case it can help others.

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass');
mysql_select_db('db');
$query="select *from table WHERE username='$username' ";
$run=mysql_query($query);
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($run))
```

Comment: $_SESSION is an array, so your code make  no sense. i would expect `SELECT * FROM users where id =$_SESSION[id]`

Comment: I just figured it out on with messing around with code. Thanks for the reply. I am going to post the code that I use in case it can help other people.

Comment: you should instantly stop using `mysql_*` its going to be removed from php

Comment: I have only been taught mysql. How different is mysqli from mysql?

Comment: then your teachers are doing you a great disservice. Cheap and dirty, adding an **i** is 90% of the difference

Comment: Thank you for the heads up and the response.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not `mysql_query("SELECT $_SESSION from users",$db)` because `$_SESSION`, in PHP terms, is an array.
If anything, an array needs to be serialized/unserialized before/after storing it in SQL database.